# Get Next/Previous song from android playlist

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm writing an android music player and I'm having problems finding the next song in a playlist. 
I have two values for a song, 
the playlistID (MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAYLIST_ID) 
and the playlist song ID MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members._ID

here is the relevant code, attempting to get a cursor over all songs after the current one:

```
    Uri qUri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", playlistId);

    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0 AND " + MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members._ID + " > " + songId +
            " AND "+ MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAYLIST_ID + " = " + playlistId;

    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members._ID };


    Cursor cursor;
    /* Execute query. */
    try{
        cursor = mContentResolver.query(qUri, projection, selection, null, null);
    } catch(SQLiteException s)
    {
        ReconApp.debugToast("SQLiteException in next track finder", ReconApp.ERROR_TOAST);
        s.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
```

it catches the following exception

```
10-14 14:24:08.207: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(1479): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: ambiguous column name: _id: , while compiling: SELECT audio_playlists_map._id AS _id FROM audio_playlists_map, audio WHERE (audio._id = audio_id AND playlist_id = 1) AND (is_music != 0 AND _id > 29 AND playlist_id = 1)
```

for some reason it searches two tables: audio_playlists_map, audio, which seems to be the source of the problem.

is it possible to find the next song with these values? It will complicate my program to have to handle playlist songs differently and store some other value, which I don't even know what it would be, MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID maybe?

Comment: This will help, hopefully (though it is an undocumented way) - http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/finding-the-songtrack-which-is-currently-playing-in-android

Answer (score 2):

//You can only seek and append. Try This

```
 String[] projection = new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAYLIST_ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID};
            Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", _playlistid);
            contentUri = contentUri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("limit", "1").build();
            Cursor playlistCursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
                    projection,
                    null, null, MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER);
```